# layout like spider

Tags: android, layout

I want a cylindrical, spider web like layout:

[image]

I know that I can use canvas to draw this but I also need all portions to be clickable, and canvas is very hard to handle touch for all portion.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can i want layout like spider...

Yes you can want it. But if you want to actually create that layout then you cannot do it with the standard android widgets.

If you want to make it then I would suggest drawing it on a Canvas manually and using the onTouchListener to catch the key presses.

Comment: yes, you are right but it is very hard to draw and also add some text in all portion, so it is really very hard to catch the key presses for all text using onTouchListener. no any otherway..?

Comment: I think you can't even use standard View-ViewGroup framework since it supports only rectangular views. Yeah it's very complicated task and there is no otherway.

Comment: @CapDroid yeah buddy there is no other way!!

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure but i hope this can help you ...

The Path class holds a set of vector-drawing commands such as lines,
rectangles, and curves. Here’s an example that defines a circular path:

```
circle = new Path();
circle.addCircle(150, 150, 100, Direction.CW);
```

This defines a circle at position x=150, y=150, with a radius of 100
pixels. Now that we’ve defined the path, let’s use it to draw the circle’s
outline plus some text around the inside:

```
private static final String QUOTE = "Now is the time for all " +
"good men to come to the aid of their country." ;
canvas.drawPath(circle, cPaint);
canvas.drawTextOnPath(QUOTE, circle, 0, 20, tPaint);
```

You can see the result in this Figure

[image: This is figure]

If you want to get really fancy, Android provides a number of `PathEffect`
classes that let you do things such as apply a random permutation to a
path, cause all the line segments along a path to be smoothed out with
curves or broken up into segments, and create other effects.