# How can I create the following UI in android?

Tags: android

How can I make this kind of UI in android? Are there any frameworks for UI designs?

[image]

Please help me out!

Comment: I'm quite sure that it is OpenGL.

Comment: Agreed.  I think those are drawn with OpenGL.  You could, in theory, make this with like a FrameLayout, but it would be mind-boggling and horrendous.

Comment: @milind do u mean just the layout?

Comment: no i want to create it with functionality like zoom in and zoom out actually it is iphone application for music playing. in that all circle are artist it play the particular song when u click on that. that mean it need on touch event of all circle.

Comment: If these bubbles have animation, I think you are going to have to perform custom painting (in a Canvas, for example), and manage gestures by yourself.

Comment: i tried on custome painting but in that case i cant get touch event of particulate bubbles.

Comment: i also facing like as this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882199/layout-like-spider but my designer made that layout and now i m contrasting only on that "how to handle touch on all portion"

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three possibilities you should consider investigating. In no particular order:

- [Renderscript](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/introducing-renderscript.html)
- [cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/)
- [Drawing on the canvas](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

the andEngine make possible to draw this kind of UI and touch event of any bauble.
to more detail che the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662920/android-canvas-draw-circles-and-get-touch-events/6663118#6663118)