# is it posible to call java class from javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, android

I need to make some UI part in javascript for android application for that I'm writing some code in javascript and load it in android web view. Now, I want to call java class from javascript.

Is it possible to call java class from javascript?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why are you splitting the application that way?  Why not just write it all,including UI, in Java?

Comment: because i need to draw much complex UI in android you can see the following question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/6596294/562296

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the following urls,

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0170.html

Post #6 of-> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=565819

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 4):

It's possible, but I wouldn't do it for your given use case :) (the UI could be done with the Android framework)

You can add what they call "Javascript Interfaces", which are basically links from Javascript to Java code. First, define a class to bind containing the methods you which to call, and add it to your WebView :

```
    class HelloInterface  
    {  
        public void test(String name)  
        {  
            Log.i(TAG, "Hello " + name); 
        }  
    } 

    webview.addJavascriptInterface(new HelloInterface(), "HELLO");
```

Then, from your javascript code, you can just call

```
window.HELLO.test("Webview");
```

Comment: I meant I wouldn't use javascript just to create a UI that could be done with the native Android framework :)  Besides that, binding java and javascript is fine.

Answer (score 0):

its actually reall easy (and cool) use:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(js, "pageObject");
```

js is a java object made in you activty (or somewhere where you init the webview), pageObject is the namespace identifier (variable) you can use with javaScript on your webpage.