# android canvas draw circles and get touch events

Tags: android, touch, zooming, shapes, android-canvas

i have been trying to make such a demo where i need to **draw** many(hundreds of) **circle** shapes on **canvas**(or any other way if possible) ,

after drawing the canvas i need to **zoom and move it**..

and also want to capture the ***click(touch) event of each shape separately*** ..

so i know i can get canvas touch event and get x and y positions and check which which circle is touched but i have to draw many circles and as well **after zooming and moving the circle's x and y pos is changes** so plz help me..

Give me any **suggestion** how to do this..the way to go..
or if any ANDROID MASTER have done some thing like this..plz plz give me **code sample**..

thank you all,
good day..

Answer (score 2):

according your requirement you have 2 use one of the android game framework you can find so many game engine [check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633366/game-engine-for-android) or you can use andengine one of the best 2D game engine in that you can find many example code.

for your requirement just follow the PinchZoomExample from [here](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/)

any further help comment the question i love to help this prob.

Comment: thanks for the answer.. i will try and let you know if i had any questions regarding that..!

Comment: hi..
I have a same problem:
I'm drawing and pasting image on canvas. 
Problem is when I zoom in/out or Drag the canvas, then I don't get the correct position of the canvas. Like if i've touched at 100,100 it might give me 256,450..
Plz guide me to solve it. I want correct cordinates after draging or  scaling the canvas.