# Android - Is it possible to have dynamically moving clickable objects in a view

Tags: android, view, extend

For the purposes of say game development, is it possible to set up a view and create a class that extends button or implements clickable or something. Im trying to figure out the best way to handle screen clicks on moving objects onscreen and right now Im drawing everything in a canvas which inturn is drawn to a view but I cant make individual bitmaps representing objects clickable.

So before I throw out a lot of work already and try for it does anyone know if its possible to have dynamically moving objects within a view that can independently handle screen clicks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662920/android-canvas-draw-circles-and-get-touch-events or http://praveenmax.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/painting-a-circle-using-touchlistener/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an [`OnTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) to your view (the one that that draws all your objects on the canvas), and in the `onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)`, get the coordinates of the event:

```
int x = event.getX();
int y = event.getY();
```

Then loop through your objects that you draw and see if these coordinates are on that objects current area, if so, you know that it has been clicked.

Comment: I have already implemented this but for some reason my clicks do not register correctly about 75% of the time. I have a ListArray of objects in memory for that particular instance and if the device registers a screen click then a fire a custom made method which iterates through all the objects in the listarray until the coordinates of one of the items in the list match that of the screen click. Like i said this works some times and usually works for 0-5 onscreen objects but at some times I will have more than 40 or 50 objects on screen and some of them actually infront of one another.

Comment: its at the time that I have large numbers of objects onscreen that this current method Im using breaks down and becomes unreliable. So.....Im trying to come up with a way to make an object that has the properties of a view I can use to draw in my view and Im not sure if that will work. If each object is something like a view I can just have it reference itself for the click rather than start a process of iterating through an array of up to possibly 80 or more objects some of which maybe overlapping one another onscreen at the moment.

Comment: I think it will be more efficient to do as you do now though, what you need with that many objects is a list that is sorted, so that the objects drawn above other objects register the click, and not something behind it.

Comment: Yeah Ive been concerned about trying extend a view with an object due to performance issues but Im not sure. I did try this before but for some reason all the objects on screen where drawn in the upper right hand corner of the screen and I couldnt get them to move anymore. Ill try cleaning up my code and try to get better click handling performance out of it.